# How can I filter a table with data from another in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two columns with dates and times. I would like to get all the data from another table that is between the times in column `ort` and `ocas`. For example, all the data between: `1/1/2012 9:04 AM` to `1/1/2012 6:12 PM` AND `2/ 1/2012 9:04` to `1/2/2012 18:13` etc

[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iedRS.png)

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5cs8.png)

```
select * FROM camarinas
WHERE  data
 between (select ort from ort_ocas) 
 and (select ocas from ort_ocas);
```

Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM camarinas
  WHERE `data` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `data` FROM camarinas
      JOIN ort_ocas
      ON `data` BETWEEN Ort AND Ocas  
  );
```

Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  30.016 sec

Comment: It takes a lot longer for me to set up a test bed than it would be for you to publish sample data and expected outcome as text..so I guess you are in no hurry.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. First is the `Id` column here a foreign key in the `ort_ocas`?

Comment: What I am looking for is to filter all the data of image 2 with the dates of image 1. Only take the data that is between the values of image 1.

Comment: Hello @AbdulrahmanAli. no, they are independent tables. Image 1 is the hours at which it dawns and dusk. I am looking for image 2 to only show two data when it is daytime. But there is no relationship between them

Comment: A query that **might** work is the following: 
`SELECT * FROM camarinas JOIN ort_ocas ON data = Ort WHERE data between Ort AND Ocas`. Not sure whether it's gonna work, though.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli dont work. I looking for some like https://imgur.com/a/7zvAje3

Comment: Hey @FranciscoJGarciaCorbeira, Why don't you use this query `SELECT * FROM camarinas WHERE data IN (SELECT data FROM camarinas AS table1 JOIN ort_ocas ON data BETWEEN Ort AND Ocas);`. I saw you're using something similar in your comment below on @P.Salmon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

JOIN ON..between

```
DROP TABLE IF exists t,t1;

create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key, dt date);
create table t1
(dt1 date,dt2 date);

insert into t(dt) values
('2022-08-10'),('2022-09-01'),('2022-10-01');
insert into t1 values
('2022-08-01','2022-08-31'),
('2022-09-01','2022-09-30');

select id,dt,dt1,dt2 
from t
join t1 on dt between dt1 and dt2;

+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | dt         | dt1        | dt2        |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2022-08-10 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-31 |
|  2 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-30 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/nkW9zDsB
More or less like this, because I have several fields in image 2